# Where i should implement the data validation server-client architecture app?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, wcf, client-server

What is the best side to put the data validation error (ex:required property), in server-client architecture app,are lives in client side or at the server side.

Comment: you should do simple validation checks on the Client-Side of code.. why to any potential postbacks just have have data that could have checked prior to submitting data to the web server, when you can do that in code in regards to Client-Side Code..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want validation in the client and on the server. You want to stop bad requests early and you must protect your service (and perhaps data) on the server-side.